# Python UDP and TCP communication between VMware host and guest not working

Tags: python, sockets, udp, virtual-machine

I am using VMWare workstation with a Windows 7 host and a Ubuntu guest. I am trying to have communication between the two with either UDP or TCP--have not had success with either. I have my VM set to Bridged networking mode which gives it its own IP address. I have the most basic TCP/UDP server and client code from any example site online which I've tested and works fine If I run both on the host machine. However, when I have either the client or the server on the VM, the communication does not go through.

To try and figure out what's going on, I ran the UDP server on the host machine and ran Wireshark on the host with it filtered to UDP; then I tried sending a packet from the client on the guest, and in wireshark I can see the the packet is going through but the server just does not seem to want to receive it. Any ideas?

UDP Server:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

    print >>sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address)
    print >>sys.stderr, data

    if data:
        sent = sock.sendto(data, address)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sent %s bytes back to %s' % (sent, address)
```

UDP Client:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('192.168.100.38', 10000)
message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'

try:

    # Send data
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)

    # Receive response
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive'
    data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

In wireshark I can see the packet that is sent from the VM client:

Src=192.168.100.42 Dst=192.168.100.38 Proto=UDP

Comment: Look at this: `server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 10000)` it shoudnt look like that. Either A. get nginx to forward that port out, or B. change the `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` and if that doesnt work, youre doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
```

you tell the socket to listen on packets addressed to 127.0.0.1:10000 but the incoming packages goes to 192.168.100.37:10000. Try

```
bind(('0.0.0.0', 10000)
```

Comment: beat you by 30 seconds! :P You still get an upvote :P

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work when the client is on the VM.

Comment: Did you change server to bind(0.0.0.0, 10000)?

Because if you only changed that you run it from the client you still send the packages to 192.168.100.37, not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes. I updated the code. Just tested with exact code from post and it works when both server and client are on host machine. But not with client on VM.

Comment: hmm wierd, tried it in the following ways

ubuntu(host)->ubuntu(host)

ubuntu(host)->centos(guest)

centos(guest)->centos(guest)

Comment: Have you tried running only the server on the guestos and then also on the guestos run "echo hej | nc 127.0.0.1 10000 -u"

Comment: try "echo hej | nc 192.168.100.38 10000 -u" and "server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 10000)" respectively, might corner in the issue